# prepend html data in two section of page at once

Tags: php, ajax

I have ajax setup to submit code to create a new category to the database and then it prepends it back to the page and shows it without the page refreshing. I can even pull the exact same data on different areas of the page at once.

Here is where I get stuck. My goal is finding a way to prepend two different data sets. One that goes under the new categories as it already does, and then another that just pulls in a  field on the create a new post section of the page. I thought it might be something by a element id or something but I can't find much on what I am looking for.

So is it possible to take a prepend(html) and submit the data differently to two page areas at once?

Here is my code for the submission.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function() {
        $(".update_button").click(function() {
            var boxval = $("#category").val();
            var boxval = encodeURIComponent(boxval);
            var dataString1 = 'category='+ boxval;

            var dataConfirm = 'newFAQCategory=true';
            var dataString = dataString1+'&'+dataConfirm;
            if(boxval=='') {
                alert("Please Enter A Title");
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "ajax/faqCN.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        $("ol#update").prepend(html);
                        $("select#faqc_id").prepend(html);
                        $("ol#update li:first").slideDown("slow");
                        document.getElementById('category').value='';
                        document.getElementById('category').focus();
                    }
                });
            } return false;
        });
    });


 </script>
```

Comment: Instead of returning the html could you return a json string with 2 different sets of html. then in the ajax success code you could put .prepend(html.category)

Comment: How would you go about doing that exactly? I have it submitting to a php file that just runs the mysqli query, then echos out the html which gets returned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement @Brett's suggestion, which is, instead of sending just HTML code to your AJAX request, send a JSON with the two pieces of HTML, you'd need something like this:

PHP AJAX response:

```
$returnValue = array();
$returnValue["html1"] = "<b>html for new categories</b>";
$returnValue["html2"] = "<b>html for new post section</b>";
exit(json_encode($returnValue));
```

Then in JavaScript you'd have:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/faqCN.php",
    data: dataString,
    dataType: "json", // type of data that you're expecting back from the server
    cache: false
})
.done(function(data) {
    // Put the HTML received in the right place
    $("#html1").prepend(data.html1);
    $("#html2").prepend(data.html2);
});
```

One last note, the "success" callback is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8, so it's recommended to use `.done()` instead.